# Commutative Count in a groupby dataframe on other columns condition

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I'm looking out for some help with the following Data Frame. I need to create a New column which starts counting the value in a groupby coulmn when Activity = 1

i.e. for every A in column 'ID' when'Activity' is 1, it should start counting till the next value in 'ID' comes

```
f=pd.DataFrame({'ID':list('AAAAABBBBBBCCCCC'),'Activity':[0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,0]})
```

I have tried the following :

```
f['New Column'] = f.groupby(['ID', f.Activeity.cumsum()]).Activeity.apply(lambda x(x^1).cumsum()+1)
f
```

But unfortunately I'm not getting the output that I'm looking out for

My Expected output is :

```
pd.DataFrame({'Activity':[0,0,1,2,3,0,0,1,2,1,2,0,1,1,2,3]})
f
```

Answer (score 3):

Interesting problem, multiple `1` within an `ID` makes it a little challenging:

```
s = f.groupby('ID').Activity.cumsum()

f['New Column'] = f[s>0].groupby(['ID',s]).Activity.cumcount().add(1)

f['New Column'] = f['New Column'].fillna(0)
```

Output:

```
   ID  Activity  New Column
0   A         0         0.0
1   A         0         0.0
2   A         1         1.0
3   A         0         2.0
4   A         0         3.0
5   B         0         0.0
6   B         0         0.0
7   B         1         1.0
8   B         0         2.0
9   B         1         1.0
10  B         0         2.0
11  C         0         0.0
12  C         1         1.0
13  C         1         1.0
14  C         0         2.0
15  C         0         3.0
```

Comment: **Thanks a lot Quang Hoang**

It was exactly what I was looking out for..

Answer (score 1):

Using combination of `cummax` and `cumsum`

```
s = df.Activity.cumsum()
s1 = df.Activity.groupby(df.ID).cummax()
df['C_Activity'] = s1.groupby([df.ID, s]).cumsum()

Out[49]:
   ID  Activity  C_Activity
0   A         0           0
1   A         0           0
2   A         1           1
3   A         0           2
4   A         0           3
5   B         0           0
6   B         0           0
7   B         1           1
8   B         0           2
9   B         1           1
10  B         0           2
11  C         0           0
12  C         1           1
13  C         1           1
14  C         0           2
15  C         0           3
```

Comment: **Thanks** Andy!

It has helped me to achieve what I was looking out for

Answer (score 0):

```
f=pd.DataFrame({'ID':list('AAAAABBBBBBCCCCC'),'Activity':[0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,0]})
new_data = pd.DataFrame()
for id, number in f["ID"].value_counts().iteritems():
  new_numbers = []
  data = f[f["ID"] == id]
  count = 0
  for index, elements in data.iterrows():
    if elements["Activity"]:
      count = 0
      new_numbers.append(1)
      count = 1
    else:
      if count:
        count = count + 1
        new_numbers.append(count)
      else:
        new_numbers.append(0)
  data["Activity"] = new_numbers
  new_data = new_data.append(data)
new_data = new_data.sort_values("ID")
```

Check `new_data`